# Getting all documents uids from firestore and add them to a list .flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I created a new collection named users on my firestore project. Im trying to get a list of all auto generated id's in that collection. So far I tried

```
  late List<String> userID = [];
  Future getID() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get().then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
            userID.add(document.reference.id);
          }),
        );
  }
```

But whenever I try to access the Strings of id's in the list , it returns an empty list

Answer (score 0):

`getID` is a future method. It will take some to fetch data. After getting data you need to call setState to update the UI. You dont need to `await` and `.then` same time

try

```dart
Future getID() async {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get().then((snapshot) {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
      userID.add(document.reference.id);
    });
    setState(() {});
  });
}
```

It would be great to use FutureBuilder for future method.